# DataContract boolean property always setting as false

Tags: ios, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, datacontract

In my MVC4 Project, i am having one object called Status.

```
[DataContract]
public class Status
{
   [DataMember(Name = "Admin")]
   public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Settings(Status data)
{
}
```

But whenever calling the api method `Settings` and setting `IsAdmin` property as `true or false`, it is always setting as `false`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "ios"? Is it really related to iOS (Apple's operating system for mobile devices)?

Comment: yes `WEB API` `Settings` method is getting called from `iOS` device only

Comment: Are you using `IsAdmin`, or `Admin`?  You're declaring the name as `Admin` in the DataContract.

Comment: @Tim I am setting as `Admin` only